# Difference ACD and Survival Analysis models

Tags: survival, cox-model, autoregressive, kaplan-meier, proportional-hazards

Autoregressive conditional duration (ACD) models are typically used in econometrics for dealing with trade duration (TD) data and it is used to capture the clustering structure.

In other areas of statistics, survival models like the Cox proportional hazard, Kaplan Meier, and Accelerated Failure time (AFT) models are typically used to model duration data.

I was wondering what is the link between ACD models and survival models? Or am I seeing things incorrectly?